# How to get files from resources map in Maven project

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I have structure of project like this:

[image]

and try to create Label with image using this code

```
bAddTheme = new Label("Add theme",
                      new ImageView(new Image("images/addTheme.png")));
```

after compling get error like "Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found". How correctly to write path to file?

Comment: `new Image("com/GVArt/images/addTheme.png")`. Try looking at your folder structure outside of your IDE in order to understand it clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How @aribeiro say I take it as:

```
new Image("com/GVArt/images/addTheme.png"). Try looking at your folder structure outside of your IDE in order to understand it clearly.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bAddTheme = new Label("Add theme",
                      new Image(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("addTheme/sif.png").toExternalForm()));
```